# core audio how to generate special waveform

Tags: core-audio, wave

core audio how to generate wave like this? Generally , the wave is sine , square or sawtooth . But how to generate waveform like this ? Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TxqJ.png

Comment: This question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do? Reproduce that exact sound? Draw the picture?

Comment: Finally I found that what I should do just is generating 19khz audio . And the audio in the pic is the samples that works. thanks . I have solve the problems .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user Bjorn Roche pointed out, this is not a very clear question.  If you want that exact sound, just output the samples you see there.  If you want something similar, that example looks a bit like an amplitude modulated sinusoid.

Generating sines, saws, squares, etc. is pretty straightforward, but also boring.  Synthesizing sounds and waveforms is a large field that includes lots of differing approaches.  For getting interesting oscillator outputs, you can use a wavetable.  Beyond that, you can use standard components and then filter, modulate, etc.

Comment: Great . The question has been solved and another question comes. Could you help me solve it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204940/core-audio-generate-byte-just-like-high-for-1ms-low-for-2ms